# Prove the determinant identity

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

For any natural $n,m$ prove that

\begin{gather}
{\frac {  \left|\begin {array}{ccc} {q}^{n+m+2}&
 \left( {\frac {p}{q}} \right) ^{n+m+2}& \left( {p}^{-1} \right) ^{n+m
+2}\\ {q}^{m+1}& \left( {\frac {p}{q}} \right) ^{m+1
}& \left( {p}^{-1} \right) ^{m+1}\\ 1&1&1
\end {array} \right|   }{   \left| 
\begin {array}{ccc} {q}^{2}&{\frac {{p}^{2}}{{q}^{2}}}&{p}^{-2}
\\ q&{\frac {p}{q}}&{p}^{-1}\\ 1&1
&1\end {array} \right|   }}\\|| \\
{\frac { \left| \begin {array}{ccc} {p}^{n+m+2}&
 \left( {\frac {q}{p}} \right) ^{n+m+2}& \left( {q}^{-1} \right) ^{n+m
+2}\\ {p}^{n+1}& \left( {\frac {q}{p}} \right) ^{n+1
}& \left( {q}^{-1} \right) ^{n+1}\\ 1&1&1
\end {array} \right| }{ \left| 
\begin {array}{ccc} {p}^{2}&{\frac {{q}^{2}}{{p}^{2}}}&{q}^{-2}
\\ p&{\frac {q}{p}}&{q}^{-1}\\ 1&1
&1\end {array} \right| }}
\end{gather}

I can prove it by brute force expansion but I hope there are  more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Off-topic. Thanks for considering mobile users because of $||$ instead of one-line-expression!

Comment: It might be useful to note that
$$
\frac 12 \begin{vmatrix}
x_1&x_2&x_3\\y_1&y_2&y_3\\1&1&1
\end{vmatrix}
$$
is the area of the triangle with corners $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)$

Comment: Also, it is notable that the matrices in the denominators are [Vandermonde matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  well, that is specialized Schur polynomials

Comment: The left hand side is the Schur polynomial corresponding to the partition $\left(n+m,m\right)$ in $q$, $\dfrac{p}{q}$ and $p^{-1}$. The right hand side is the Schur polynomial corresponding to the partition $\left(n+m,n\right)$ in $q^{-1}$, $\dfrac{q}{p}$ and $p$. So you want to show that the Schur polynomial corresponding to $\left(n+m,n\right)$ equals the Schur polynomial corresponding to $\left(n+m,m\right)$ in the reciprocal variables (scaled by a power of the product of all variables, which in your case equals $1$). But this ...

Comment: ... is a particular case of a known fact (Exercise 2.9.15 (d) in [Darij Grinberg, Victor Reiner, *Hopf algebras in combinatorics*, arXiv:1409.8356v5](https://arxiv.org/src/1409.8356v5/anc/HopfComb-v73-with-solutions.pdf)), since $\left(n+m,n\right) = \left(n+m,m\right)^\vee$ (when treating both partitions as partitions with $2$ entries).

Comment: @ darij grinberg  Great!  I suspected that my identity is only a particular case. Thank you.

Comment: By direct calculation I got the following experimental formula for the Schur polynomial $s_{\lambda}$:     $$s_{m,n}(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1x_2x_2)^m s_{m,m-n}\left( \frac{1}{x_1}, \frac{1}{x_2},\frac{1}{x_2} \right)$$  or $$s_{m+m,n}(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1x_2x_2)^{m+n} s_{m+n,m}\left( \frac{1}{x_1}, \frac{1}{x_2},\frac{1}{x_2} \right).$$