# Prove the determinant identity (2)

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, determinant

For any natural $n$  prove that

\begin{gather*}
{\frac {  q \left|\begin {array}{ccc} {q}^{n+2}&
 \left( {\frac {p}{q}} \right) ^{n+2}& \left( {p}^{-1} \right) ^{n
+2}\\ {q}&  {\frac {p}{q}} &  {p}^{-1} \\ 1&1&1
\end {array} \right|  - p \left|\begin {array}{ccc} {q}^{n+1}&
 \left( {\frac {p}{q}} \right) ^{n+1}& \left( {p}^{-1} \right) ^{n
+1}\\ {q}&  {\frac {p}{q}} &  {p}^{-1} \\ 1&1&1
\end {array} \right|   }{   \left| 
\begin {array}{ccc} {q}^{2}&{\frac {{p}^{2}}{{q}^{2}}}&{p}^{-2}
\\ q&{\frac {p}{q}}&{p}^{-1}\\ 1&1
&1\end {array} \right|   }}\\|| \\q\frac{\begin{vmatrix} q^{n+1} & p^{-(n+1)} \\ 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix} q& p^{-1} \\ 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}}.
 \end{gather*}
I can prove it by brute force expansion but I hope there are more elegant way to do it.

See also [My old similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3262385/prove-the-determinant-identity)

Comment: $p,q$ can take any real value $\neq 0$ ? Or do you prefer to consider them as indeterminates ?

Comment: $p,q$ are formal parameters

Comment: I really can't understand what is your intention